# Multiple jQuery tooltips with different content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using jQuery tooltip to display an image (thumbnail preview) when hovering over a text link as shown here (https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content).

This works fine in its essence, but at present every link shows the same image on hover. What I want is for the tooltip on each link to display an image unique to that link (effectively previewing the content of the link).

*I have a basic understanding of both HTML and CSS but JavaScript and jQuery I'm still struggling with – so any help is greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget photo">
  <div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <h1>
    <a href="/uploads/test1.jpeg" data-geo="">Test1.</a>
    <a href="/uploads/test2.jpeg" data-geo="">Test2.</a>
    <a href="/uploads/test3.jpeg" data-geo="">Test3.</a>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $( function() {
      $( document ).tooltip({
          items: "img, [data-geo], [title]",
          content: function() {
              var element = $( this );
              if ( element.is( "[data-geo]" ) ) {
                  var text = element.text();
                  return "<img class='map' alt='" + text +
                      "' src='/uploads/hello.jpeg'>";
              }
              if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
                  return element.attr( "title" );
              }
              if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
                  return element.attr( "alt" );
              }
          }
      });
  } );
```

As above, Test1, Test2, and Test3 would all have unique images in their tooltips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should replace with this:

```
$( function() {
      $( document ).tooltip({
          items: "img, [data-geo], [title]",
          content: function() {
              var element = $( this );
              if ( element.is( "[data-geo]" ) ) {
                  var text = element.text();
                  return "<img class='map' alt='" + text +
                      "' src='" + element.attr('href') + "'>";
              }
              if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
                  return element.attr( "title" );
              }
              if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
                  return element.attr( "alt" );
              }
          }
      });
  } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(element.is("[data-geo]")){
   var text = element.text();
   return `<img class='map' alt=${text} src='${element.attr('href')}'>`;
}
```

Now you use fixed image
`return "<img class='map' alt='"+text+"'src='/uploads/hello.jpeg'>"`

You should change dynamic image `src`.